# Run app without task bar icon

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-5

I am running a small monitoring program that has a form/window that stays on top on the corner of my screen. At present it has an icon in the Windows Task Bar. I would like to remove this icon and have either none at all or an icon in the System Tray. (Win XP)

I am using Delphi 5 (yes I know, dark ages). I gather it is easy to do what I want using later Delphi versions, but I don't know how to achieve it in D5 by using system messages.

The MainFormOnTaskBar property is not available in Delphi 5, so this needs to be achieved using Windows messages, which I am unfamiliar with.

Suggestions please.

Comment: Delphi 5 is equivalent to `MainFormOnTaskBar := False`. That is the main form's owner is the Application` window. That is, `Application.Handle`. That's the window that is on the taskbar. So you just need to hide that application window. As the answers in the dupe say. It's that simple.

Comment: Thanks David. I'm sure it's simple when you know it. I eventually got it to work using the CreateParams procedure shown in the second answer. Nothing else I tried worked.